# Color de fondo agregado en input Angular

Tags: css, input, angular7, angular-material

El inconveniente es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo elijo alguna de las opciones que complete el formulario este le agrega un color blanco por ejemplo, pero si escribo completamente de manera manual obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tiene ningún color solo esta así el input, he leído la documentación y no encuentro algo parecido para poder solucionarlo, no se si sea con CSS o alguna propiedad como tal de angular material.

**Actualización**

Buscando por la red, en resumen lo que pasa es que Chrome agrega un fondo, ejemplo como el de la primera imagen, y una solución para mi y algunas personas que vi en la pregunta fue la siguiente:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 50000s ease-in-out 0s, color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Es agregar en css y des habilita el fondo que le pone Chrome

Answer (score 0):

con esto se puede controlar el color cuando el input tiene datos guardados por el navegador

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset !important;
 }
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: white, 0 0 0 50px white inset;
 }
```